# Can any one find me perl regular expressions for the following expressions?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to convert the below list of expressions to their perl regular expression equivalents. To search for that pattern in the string.
In below expressions VARNAME is dynamic. It can be any word value.

```
 EXPRESSION                                     PERL REGULAR EXPRESSION
__________________                                _________________________
    ^TM1()^
    ^TM2()^
    ^TM3()^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’)^           ----------------        /\^f\(‘(\w*?)’\)\^/  
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).get()==’#’^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’)==’#’^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).any(‘#’)^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).toNumber()^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).toString()^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toLowerCase()^
    ^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toUpperCase()^
    ^f(‘IFCONDITION’)?’THENTEXT’:’ELSETEXT’^
    <br>
    <br/>
    <br />
    &nbsp;
    ^MobileHeader()^
    ^MobileFooter()^
    <u>
    </u>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having? These all look pretty simple to convert, you just need to escape the special characters.

Comment: @sampath_t You could use index with regular strings.

Comment: @Barmar : I'm a SAS developer(new to perl)...Just came to know that there are some perl functions in SAS which are useful for my current project.But I need to convert those expressions in to perl regular expressions before I can use perl functions in SAS....I would appreciate your help if you can convert those for me...Thanks,Sam.

Comment: @kjprice : Yeah I tried index too but we can't use wildcards in index function.....Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: We're not here to do your work for you, we're here to answer questions when you run into problems. Go to regular-expressions.info if you need an introduction to regexps.

Comment: I suspect IFCONDITION, THENTEXT, and ELSETEXT are also dynamic?  If so, what all could they be?  Is anything else dynamic?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
while (<DATA>) {
   chomp;
   print quotemeta($_), "\n";   # or:  print "\Q$_\E\n";
}

__DATA__
^TM1()^
^TM2()^
^TM3()^
^f(‘VARNAME’)^
^f(‘VARNAME’).get()==’#’^
^f(‘VARNAME’)==’#’^
^f(‘VARNAME’).any(‘#’)^
^f(‘VARNAME’).toNumber()^
^f(‘VARNAME’).toString()^
^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toLowerCase()^
^f(‘VARNAME’).toString().toUpperCase()^
^f(‘IFCONDITION’)?’THENTEXT’:’ELSETEXT’^
<br>
<br/>
<br />
&nbsp;
^MobileHeader()^
^MobileFooter()^
<u>
</u>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "or" them all, escaping as necessary. You can shorten it somewhat using '?'.

This is not a clean or elegant solution, but I guess it will work well for your purposes.

Comment: perhaps better suited as a comment...